# Metal equivalent for glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH)

Tags: metal, metalkit

I cannot seem to find a similar feature to glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH) in metal. Is it possible to do this in metal? If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: To my knowledge closest you can get is using MSAA.